# Regexp all but omit attributes containing data

Tags: php, regex, attributes, tags, preg-replace

For example I have a text:

```
Bla bla one two three <b> just another test Romans 12:5 </b>
Okay next line and next text Romans 12:5
And this text is important too Romans 12:5
<іmg src="/іmg.png" title="Romans 12:5" alt="Romans 12:5" someattr="Romans 12:5" />
<a title="Romans 12:5" href="/link.html">Romans 12:5</a>
```

I need to catch:

```
Romans 12:5
```

But the regexp must omit text placed on the attributes (alt,title,anyone) and omit text placed in the `<a>` tags too.

I have similar regexp but it catches everything including atributes containing text:

```
Romans(\?| |\.|\. |\.\r\n|\r\n)([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,3})
```

BTW I use PHP preg_replace with this regexp and this text modifies like this:

```
<a href=\"http://site.com/Romans/\\7\\3#\\4\" target=\"Romans 12:5\">\\1</a>
```

Who know a modernized way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to format all the question as code

Comment: What's the purpose of this exactly? Is it always going to be Roman 12:5 or what other possible formats can it be? What are you replacing exactly?

Comment: @Gary Green: The end purpose is to convert plaintext verses of the Bible to hyperlinks. So it can be not only Romans and not only numbers 12 or 5. For example, **Exodus 1:1** or **3 John 2:1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^">]{1}(Romans \d{1,3}:\d{1,3})[^"<]{1}
```

Matches the three instances of *Romans 12:5* outside the attributes and `<a>` tag.

Edit: in order to match the additional requirements, you can use this:

```
(?:[^">]|^){1}(Romans \d{1,3}:\d{1,3})(?:[^"<]|$){1}
```

If this still doesn't fit with what you need, [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/) has a wealth of regular expressions for all kinds of scenarios that you can adapt to suit your needs, such as [this one](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2449).

Comment: I mean 17:1, 19 and 20-25 are 3 different links.

Comment: @Skyman: 17:1 would already be matched, I've updated my answer for the other two.  If you're after multiple books too then you're getting very much into the realms of false positives as you're effectively looking for 'some text followed by a number', so things like June 1 would be matched.

Comment: All book names are in array, so there is no false positives have to be.

Comment: @Skyman: Good stuff.  If you need to edit regular expressions with any regularity, I'd recommend having a play with [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: Arhh.. The problem is not solved yet. When I try this example the first occurrence is not found by regexp you given me:
Romans 12:5 Bla bla one two three <b> just another test Romans 12:5
<a title="Romans 12:5" href="/link.html">Romans 12:5</a>. I mean that regexp don't see 1st "Romans 12:5". Btw it caches space symbol also before. But why?

Comment: @SkyMan: I've updated it again to handle beginning (^) and end ($) of string.  Running it through Expresso the matches don't contain spaces, make sure you're referring to the captured group rather than the whole matched string. I can't really help on the PHP side of things I'm afraid, but this may help: [Regular Expressions in PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

Comment: So. One more bug. This regexp catches spaces before and after. Right version: "Romans 12:5". Wrong (current) version: " Romans 12:5 " (with spaces). How to fix it?

Comment: @Skyman: The first capture group contains the string without spaces - I'm not sure about working with regexes in PHP but have a look at that link I posted a couple of comments up as that'll probably help with how to extract and use that capture group.